# Javascript case insensitive regex span

Tags: javascript, regex, pcre

Is there a workaround to provide case-insensitive matches within a *span* of a regular expression?

PCRE provides this ability:

```
preg_match("/(?i:ab)cd/", "aBcd"); //evaluates to 1
preg_match("/(?i:ab)cd/", "aBCd"); //evaluates to 0
```

All I can find are global flags:

```
"aBcd".match(/abcd/i); //match found, CORRECT
"aBCd".match(/abcd/i); //match found, INCORRECT
```

Alternatively, I could escape each character

```
"aBcd".match(/[Aa][Bb]cd/i)
```

...but this becomes very clunky for long strings.

Comment: I don't believe those work in JS.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: indeed

Comment: A way can be to use the global flag, to delimit sensitive and insensitive parts with capture groups and to check them separately.